# Alignment problem with algorithmic and hyperref

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hyperref, algorithms

I have some alignment problems in the `algorithmic` environment when I use the
`hyperref` package. I like to have my comments left-aligned which I achieve
by `\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill(#1)}` in the preamble.

It turns out that comments on lines before `\ENDFOR` or anline break
(which I use to identify different blocks of code) are a bit misaligned.

Here is a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill(#1)}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE foo
  \COMMENT{bar}
\FOR{foo}
  \STATE foo
    \COMMENT{bar}
  \STATE foo
    \COMMENT{bar}
\ENDFOR
\STATE foo
  \COMMENT{bar}
\STATE foo
  \COMMENT{bar} \\[0.5em]
\STATE foo
  \COMMENT{bar}
\RETURN foo
  \COMMENT{bar}
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Please comment `\usepackage{hyperref}` to have the desired output:

[image]

My guess is some weird interaction between `\end{list}` which is used by
`algorithmic` and `hyperref`, but I'm kind of stuck now. Do you have any
suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your comment, use

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill(#1)\ignorespaces}
```

which gobbles any spaces after `\COMMENT`, effectively being the same as inserting `%` after each one. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 2):

A work around is to comment out the end of line characters after the `\COMMENT` commands:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill(#1)}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE foo
  \COMMENT{bar}%
\FOR{foo}
  \STATE foo
    \COMMENT{bar}%
  \STATE foo
    \COMMENT{bar}%
\ENDFOR
\STATE foo
  \COMMENT{bar}%
\STATE foo
  \COMMENT{bar}\\[0.5em]
\STATE foo
  \COMMENT{bar}%
\RETURN foo
  \COMMENT{bar}
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Exactly what in `hyperref` is causing an extra an extra box here is not clear to me.  `algothrimc` does some quite heaving modification of `\item` commands in the custom list environment, which could be a source of the bad interaction.